# Djvu reader with drawing and writing support for annotations?

Tags: windows, annotation, djvu

I just got a Djvu document that I'd love to annotate with my Surface Pro 3, using the included pen. But neither of the good Djuv readers I like (WinDjView and DjView) support penning or annotation in any way. I know some PDF readers allow you to write and annotate documents, are there any Djvu applications that let you do the same thing?

Comment: If you were just looking for a viewer i would point you to irfanview with plugin. But in your case you might look into here. Have to say didnt tried it hence just commenting instead of answering. http://djvu.sourceforge.net/features.html